# Searching rows of one dataframe in another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, list, search, dataframe

I have two data frames in python:

```
  df1
       A     B     C
       1     1     0
       1     2     1 
       0     1     2
       .     .     .
       .     .     .

  df2
       T     W    S    Y
       7     4    5   [1]
       8     12   4   [0,7]
       10    14   6   [2,3]
```

I want to go through all rows of df1 and find the observations in df2 with the following characteristics:

```
     (T <= A) and (W > A) and (S == B) and (sum(pd.Series(Y).isin([C])) != 0)
```

Obviously, using for loop is not efficient but could you please tell me how can I solve my problem? I've heard that I could vectorization technique like Matlab but I'm not sure if we have such technique in python or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a merge of the two dataframes and filter the result. I am not sure how optimized it will be, but it will do the job faster than python for loops.